# Regex - совпадение строк без включения самих совпадений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

```
String regex = "href=\"(.*?)\"";
```

В результате будет строка:

```
href="http://someurl.ru"
```

Можно ли написать regex, который не будет включать в себя href=" в начале и " в конце строки?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы скобки уберите, либо берите у матчера нулевой результат (вся строка)

**UPD**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String mySource = "<a href=\"http://test1.ru\" /> <a href=\"http://test2.ru\" />";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"").matcher(mySource);

        while(m.find()) {
            MatchResult mr = m.toMatchResult();

            System.out.println(mr.group(0)); // entire match string
            System.out.println(mr.group(1)); // first group 
        }

    }
}
```

Результат:

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine:~/tests/java/27> javac Main.java
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine:~/tests/java/27> java Main      
href="http://test1.ru"
http://test1.ru
href="http://test2.ru"
http://test2.ru
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine:~/tests/java/27>
```

**UPD2**

Ссылки:

- [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [Pattern.compile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Pattern.matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)
- [Matcher.find](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)
- [Matcher.toMatchResult](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#toMatchResult%28%29)
- [MatchResult](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html)

Comment: Пример напишите пжл.

Comment: mr.group(1) - это то, что в скобках "(.*?)" ?

Comment: Вы можете в выражении поставить любое количество скобок. Тогда MatchResult будет содержать все результаты из всех скобок, включая случай, когда скобки вложенные. В данном случае, у вас одна пара скобок, вот и группа одна. Так что да, mr.group(1) - то что в скобках.

Comment: Советую прочесть ссылки из UPD2. Это не займёт много времени, но возможно прояснит для вас обстановку.

Comment: Круто! Всё офигенно работает.